# Vectorize list comprehension in pandas

Tags: pandas, vectorization, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with company names. I want to calculate a score for each name based on how common are the words in the name.

First, I build a dictionary of word counts. Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but the following vectorized approach works:

```
words = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(list, crsp.cname.str.split()))
```

I then count the words:

```
wordcnts = defaultdict(int)
for w in words:
    wordcnts[w] += 1
```

Now, I would like to calculate a score for each company name equal to the sum of the reciprocal of `wordcnts[word]` for each word that appears in the company name.

Right now I'm iterating over rows and using a list comprehension to calculate the sum:

```
score = {}
for idx, row in crsp.iterrows():
    score[idx] = sum([1/wordcnts[w] for w in row.cname.split()])
```

Is there a way to vectorize this last step?

Comment: it would help if had some sample data to work with

Comment: Sure, here are some company names: http://pastebin.com/hYsDzRNT

Comment: Or, for easier reading into pandas: http://pastebin.com/y3zdWgbk

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do two things to speed things up:

Replace wordCnt by a pd.DataSeries:

```
words = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(list, crsp.cname.str.split()))
wordcnts = pd.Series(collections.Counter(words))
```

And use [pd.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for faster iteration:

```
score = crsp.cname.apply(lambda x: (1.0/wordcnts[x.split()]).sum())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error: `IndexError: only integers, slices (':'), ellipsis ('...'), numpy.newaxis ('None') and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologize for the error. Try it again with my updated answer.